# Android SocialAuth for LinkedIn throws authentication error for keys

Tags: android

Has anyone tried this tool, and can confirm that its actually working?

[code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/)

I am running their samples, buy it doesnt seem to work. 
It throws authentication error for keys

Answer (score 0):

I have downlaoded their latest code from svn and it is working for linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. current available version `socialauth-android 3.2` works with `oauth1` protocol implementation for `Linkedin`. I've created [pull request](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/pull/26) with updated library `socialauth-android`, which contains new version of `socialauth` library and `oauth2` protocol implementation.

Comment: Hey i'm facing the same problem with linkdin integration. They haven't yet updated the architecture for oath in linked in. I's there anyway I could get your pull request and try it out ? I would certainly help.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/donvigo/socialauth-android/commits/master) it is, latest 2 commits.